# Constructor in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

i'm wondering is it okey to do something like this in Kotlin?

Java:

```
   public class DemoSuper {
        private int a;
        private int b;
    
        public DemoSuper(int a, int b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }
```

Kotlin.

```
class DemoClass(
        private val a: Int,
        private val b: Int
) : DemoSuper(a, b)
```

Basically, I want to call the Java constructor `DemoSuper`
from Kotlin primary constructor `DemoClass`.
I could use the super keyword in Java, but in Kotlin is it possible to do it like this?

Tnx.

Comment: You could just try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly the way you do it. Except if `DemoSuper` also has `getA()` and/or `getB()`, you should remove `private val` from `a` and/or `b` because it'll inherit the properties.